# VueJS - CSS not loaded because of its MIME type

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

Ok so I finally went back again on the awesome VueJS after few years and already stuck on this: `The stylesheet [name.css] was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`

I mean, I know the reason is because is making a redirect to the / path, which is the "landing page" of my application, so it returns an HTML, but basically I don't know how to deal with this on VueJS though.

My application is kinda dumm: A couple of .vue files, a router, and nothing more (just for keeping me updated). I use to start that via `npm run dev`.

This -> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">` is the incriminated code, with ofc its MIME type set. (ah! this code is located in the index.html, not in a .vue)

I was reading that may also be caused by having either bootstrap.css || bootstrap.min.css start with a comment (???), but I don't know how this could be logically related.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Import the css file diretly in your vue application:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
...
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css' // <-- here

...
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And you're done